# Setting C# formatting options for OmniSharp on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, omnisharp

I'm attempting to take advantage of the integration with Visual Studio Code, but can't figure out how to set the C# formatting options. The `config.json` right next to the OmniSharp exe on my Mac (`/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/jrieken.vscode-omnisharp/bin/packages/OmniSharp/config.json`) doesn't match [the standard OmniSharp `config.json` format](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-server/blob/master/OmniSharp/config.json), so setting the brace + newline behavior properties isn't working, e.g. `methodBraceStyle`. It does work to set the `tabSize`, etc., however.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I've spent half a day just trying to get my C# braces set correctly

Answer (score 34):

Just got this to work using the latest omnisharp (dev branch) and the `omnisharp.json` (pasted below) in the same folder as my project's `.sln`. 
It should work with all [releases](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/releases) since v1.9-beta18, I just compiled from source because I don't use a supported system.

```js
{
    "FormattingOptions": {
        "newLine": "\n",
        "useTabs": false,
        "tabSize": 4,
        "indentationSize": 4,

        "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInObjectCollectionArrayInitializers": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody": false,

        "NewLineForElse": false,
        "NewLineForCatch": false,
        "NewLineForFinally": false,
        "NewLineForMembersInObjectInit": false,
        "NewLineForMembersInAnonymousTypes": false,
        "NewLineForClausesInQuery": false,
    }
}
```

The available properties are listed in [`FormattingOptions.cs`](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/src/OmniSharp.Shared/Options/FormattingOptions.cs) in the [`omnisharp-roslyn` repository](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn).

Answer (score 15):

From [Configuration Options on the `omnisharp-roslyn` wiki](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options):

> At startup, OmniSharp obtains the configuration options using the following (hierarchical) order:
>
> - its own hardcoded defaults
> - Environment variables
> - Command line arguments
> - An `omnisharp.json` file located in `%USERPROFILE%/.omnisharp/`
> - An `omnisharp.json` file located in the working directory which OmniSharp has been pointed at
>
> Each of the configuration sources, can overwrite any of the settings set by the previous source.

To summarize the above configuration locations according to [a blog article by one of the developers](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/c-code-formatting-settings-in-vs-code-and-omnisharp/):

- The defaults are specified in `config.json` in the OmniSharp extension's directory.  It is **not recommend** to modify this file.
- Neither environment variables nor command line parameters are really applicable/useful for the C# extension.
- Place `omnisharp.json` in `%USERPROFILE%\.omnisharp\` (or `~/.omnisharp/`) for user-specific settings.
- Place `omnisharp.json` in a project directory for project-specific settings.
- At each level you override individual settings; you don't need to repeat the entire configuration.

Testing with v1.21.11 of the `ms-vscode.csharp` extension on Visual Code v1.42.0, it seems OmniSharp only applies `omnisharp.json` found in the root of a workspace folder, [not descendant directories](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/1208).

The [C# extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) for Visual Studio Code [also supports `EditorConfig`](https://www.strathweb.com/2019/07/editorconfig-support-in-omnisharp-and-c-extension-vs-code/), which you can enable via one of the following methods:

- `File` → `Preferences` → `Settings` → `Extensions` → `C# configuration` → `OmniSharp: Enable Editor Config Support`
- In `settings.json`...

  ```js
  {
      "omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": true,
  }
  ```
- In `omnisharp.json`

  ```js
  {
      "FormattingOptions": {
          "enableEditorConfigSupport": true
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is having issues (like I was earlier today) with Omnisharp not recognizing the omnisharp.json file put the following in your vscode `settings.json`:

`"omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": false` and `Restart Omnisharp`

Here is the link for better information on this: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5446#issuecomment-1308655891

Comment: Thank you! I've been pulling my hair for 5 hours trying to get the config to work. This was the missing piece.

Answer (score 5):

**Linux** users:

1. Go to Linux Home directory
2. Open the **.omnisharp** folder (it's hidden by default so check the "Show Hidden Files" of your file explorer)
3. Create a file **omnisharp.json**
4. Enter the [above given code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40324014/3944285)

This is the **global** solution for those who don't want to repeat the steps over and over for each project.

**IMPORTANT**: Choosing the right Linux version for installing dotNet SDK from [doc.microsoft.com/...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2010-) matters! Otherwise omnisharp will not get installed properly and the above code won't work.

Comment: Putting the onmisharp.json file in the project root didn't work for me, but this did work (Manjaro Linux), thank you.

Comment: I'm googling like an idiot, trying to figure out what this magical Home directory should be. My project folder? VS Code installation folder?

Comment: Answer states "Linux users", so i presume it is your user's home directory, usually `/home/username`.

Comment: I'm on a Debian based Linux which has a Home directory by default. It's neither your project's nor the VSCode's folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me the thing was that I had Prettier installed and configured as the default formatter (`editor.defaultFormatter`). Once I changed this setting and restarted Omnisharp, the formatting worked.

It's also important notice that the setting `omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport` should be set to `false` (as [g0nk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407922/setting-c-sharp-formatting-options-for-omnisharp-on-visual-studio-code/76346720#74482883) pointed in their answer), otherwise it won't work.